# How to downalod the format image in the datafeed

Tags: product-images, format

I would like to download the format of the images in my data feed so that I can see which ones are the wrong size.

Does anyone know how I can do that?

Comment: may I ask what consists your data feed in? is it a custom script? custom import?

Comment: It is by catalogus and than datafeed > Data Feed Manager
With this plugin https://www.wyomind.com/magento2/data-feed-manager-magento.html?section=userguide